# Checking if input field contains EN Dash or EM Dash characters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate a password field that allows special characters but does not allow the user to enter EM Dash or EN Dash, how could I check this or what would the regex look like to check for these? I'm unfamiliar with these types of dashes.

Below is my current regex that seems like it should allow everything that I specify in it, therefore; the two dashes shouldn't validate. Do I have something backwards?

```
var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-!@#$%&*]+$/;
```

Comment: Banning em and en dashes in a password is a very odd thing to do.

Comment: [and what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Agree, but it causes errors in our api if it is submitted and we need a quick fix from the front end to avoid that for now until the api issue is solved.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have added further context to my question as to show what I have tried, sorry for leaving that off initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just stick them in a character class:

```
/[–—]/
```

Break down of the characters forming that regex literal:

- U+002F : SOLIDUS
- U+005B : LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
- U+2013 : EN DASH
- U+2014 : EM DASH
- U+005D : RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
- U+002F : SOLIDUS

Comment: would I need to add them if my regex looks like this 'var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-!@#$%&*]+$/;' since this should not allow any other characters?